# How to use LINQ to set null values last in ordered list of integers

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code in a controller:

```
var orders = db.Orders
            .OrderBy(o => o.Product.Category.Sequence)
            .ToList();
```

The `OrderBy` clause orders the products by a Sequence number (an integer). The problem I have with this is that when a Category has no Sequence number, it is ordered first. I want it to be last.

How can I make the Sequence ID last in the list when it is null?

Comment: What is the value of `Sequence` if category has no sequence number?

Comment: Sequence is `nullable-int` right ?

Comment: `Sequence` is zero. That explains a lot. ;-)

Comment: @user2609980, Your title says that you get `null` values ordered first, Do you get `null` or `0` because both of them are **different**

Comment: I have made it nullable now and used the method of Habib!

Comment: Don't know why this was voted down. It's a totally valid question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
var oders = db.Orders
              .OrderBy(r=> r.Product.Category.Sequence == null)
              .ThenBy(r=> r.Product.Category.Sequence)
              .ToList();
```

If you can afford to order the records in memory *(after getting them from the database)* then you can do :

```
var newList = orders
                .OrderBy(r=> r.Prdocut.Category.Sequence ?? int.MaxValue)
                .ToList();
```

*(The above code would work with your already existing `orders` list in memory)*

Comment: I think that `Sequence` is not a nullable int according to OP's comment.

Comment: @Selman22, The title is very very misleading then "How to use LINQ to set null values last"

Comment: I agree. If values are not null then `OrderByDescending` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Selman22, No I don't think that would be enough, I think the OP wants a natural order for IDs other than `0` and at the end, wants all records with IDs set to `0`.

Comment: it's **true** if he has _negative_ Ids :)

Comment: I have made Sequence nullable now and implemented this method. I assumed it was already nullable (because it has to be), but it was not yet. :)

Answer (score 2):

If `Sequence` values are 0 instead of null then try this:

```
var orders = db.Orders
            .OrderBy(o => o.Product.Category.Sequence == 0 ? int.MaxValue : o.Product.Category.Sequence)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var orders = db.Orders
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.Product.Category.Sequence)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work, but you could also try:

```
var orders = db.Orders
            .OrderBy(o => o.Product.Category.Sequence ?? int.MaxValue)
            .ToList();
```

This is assuming that you don't have any sequences that are int.MaxValue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var orders = (from o in db.Orders
                 orderby by o.Product.Category.Sequence.HasValue descending, 
                            o.Product.Category.Sequence
                     select o).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the Sequence number is an integer, so I understand that you "when a Category
has no Sequence number" means when the Sequence is in its default value which is 0.

So I think you are looking for something like below:

```
var orders = db.Orders
        .OrderBy(o => o.Product.Category.Sequence == default(int))
        .ThenBy(o => o.Product.Category.Sequence)
        .ToList();
```